# Azure CLI not showing all keyvault vaults

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I created a keyvault and secrets from the MS docs and confirmed that I can list the keyvault and secrets from an Azure CLI session.  When somebody else granted my access to another keyvault in our Azure tenant, I am not able to list that vault from the Azure CLI. 
The CLI command I am using is :  'az keyvault list'
 I have compared the individual policies applied in two vaults, and have 'owner' role access to both.  I can see the vaults and secrets when I use a browser to navigate to the azure portal.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions on what I should check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the keyvault is in another subscription in your Azure AD tenant, in Azure CLI, you could just use `az keyvault list` to list the keyvaults in the default subscription, if you want to do operations in another subscription, you need to set the subscription with it.

Navigate to the keyvault which you want to list in the portal, copy the `Subscription ID` like below.

[image]

Then run the command below before you list the keyvaults.

```
az account set --subscription <Subscription ID>
az keyvault list
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my login had expired, but unlike with other commands, I did not get a warning to that effect. It simply returned the `[]` empty list.

Renewing my login with `az login` allowed `az keyvault list` to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to go to the subscription / RG where the key-vault was and give the user / service principal the Reader role. You can do that by clicking on the subscription/RG and then selecting "Access Control (IAM)" on the left side. And then add the role assignment. Instructions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current